# "Target text" highlight from google search

Tags: google-search, wiki

I recently noticed that when searching using google, I often land on a page with text highlighted. I can see it in Wikipedia, as well as Fandom wiki:

[image: google search for Yoda quote]

[image: star wars fandom page on The Force]

However, when I [link web-address](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_vision#targetText=%22Through%20the%20Force%2C%20things%20you,Other%20places.&targetText=Jedi%20Master%20Yoda%20was%20able,and%20even%20his%20own%20death.) from the second screenshot, I don't receive highlighted effect.

What feature is that? Is there a way I can send link to someone that would also lend them on a page with highlighting?

Answer (score 2):

This is a test by Google.

> Around 5% of search results are highlighting text on a website you visit.

Source :
https://9to5google.com/2019/08/26/google-search-highlight-website-content/
https://www.digitalinformationworld.com/2019/08/googles-feature-highlight-content.html

---

As for sharing what you see (the highlights), it's not possible with a simple link. You need to enable the feature.

Orginal tweet :
https://twitter.com/david_bokan/status/1164982909306118149

> Google Search is currently running an origin trial for ~5% of WebAnswers results so it's kind of random whether you get opted into it or not.
>
> **You can enable the feature on the client-side though using chrome://flags/#enable-text-fragment-anchor**

---